# jQuery .replace() a value (word)

Tags: jquery, html, image

Here is a jQuery code that I am using to expand a photo, as it expands I want to replace the thumbnail version of the image to the original sized version.

```
$('img.photo_share_image').click(function() {
var new_image = $(this).replace(/thumb_/ig, $(this).attr("src"));
$(this).animate({width:'100%'},500);
})
```

The original image is put onto the page by the HTML  tag. It is sourced from `http://www.example.com/thumb_someimage.jpg` what I need to do is remove the `thumb_` from the source url.

I  have already tried this by using this code

```
var new_image = $(this).replace(/thumb_/ig, $(this).attr("src"));
```

but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: replace('/thumb/imagename.jpg', $(this).attr('src'));   If IG is a variable containing the current imagename use replace('/thumb/'+ig, $(this).attr('src'));

Comment: @Jonas m : ig is not a variable but regex flags.

Comment: Ahh suddently it all made sense ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
var new_image = $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/thumb_/ig, ""));
```

Moreover, you may want to wait for your image to finish loading if it's a big one because your animation will start right after you assign a new source for your image. So, animation will not necessarily wait for it but work on the existing image DOM element.

Comment: I dint knew/remember that theres a method `.replace` I was going to try with `replaceWith()` method.

Comment: replaceWith is jQuery. What we are trying to do here is to get the string value with attr('src') then use Javascript replace function. We are using regular expression but in this case, it's a bit overkill. We could also simply use replace('thumb_','') since we know the image src attribute format. There is no need for flags like /i and /g

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're calling $(this).replace but $(this) appears to be an img element. You'd need  to call replace() on $(this).attr("src"), no?